# Cutting out spaces in Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have lot of extra space which I wish to cut out. Below is my code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Plan_Reviews__c" showHeader="false" extensions="RE">
<apex:form >

<apex:image url="{!imageURL}" style="width:720px" ></apex:image>

 <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="720px">
   <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="60%">
           <p style="font-size:18px;">FPIMS:</p> <apex:outputText value="{!p__c.test__c}" style="font-size:18px;"/>
           <p style="font-size:18px;">address: <apex:outputText value="{!p__c.ea__c}" style="font-size:18px;"/></p>

   </apex:panelGrid>
   <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="40%">         
           <p style="font-size:18px;">Date:<apex:outputText value="{!currentdate}" style="font-size:18px;"/></p>
   </apex:panelGrid>
   <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="60%">

   </apex:panelGrid>
</apex:panelGrid>  
<div id="container1" style="width:720px">

</div>

</apex:page>
</apex:form>
```

In my code here between "test:" and  container1. How can cut this space out. How do I align the content of panel grid to stick to left corners.

Comment: This code should have thrown an error that the page must be terminated by matching end-tag. If it's a typo, can you upload a screenshot of the page preview that could help us to resolve this.

Comment: I pasted only half of the code just to give an idea. Main problem is how I can remove the extra space coming up between panelgrid and div container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the < p> tag you are using inside the PanelGrid might cause an extra space. You said what you have posted is only half of the code. If the below code works, make these changes to the rest of the code.

1. Moved < /apex:form> tag inside the < apex:page>
2. Replaced  < p> tag with < span>
3. Created a style class for left alignment of all the contents in the Panel Grid

   ```
   <apex:page standardController="Plan_Reviews__c" showHeader="false" extensions="RangehoodObjectionExtention">
       <style>
       .alignfontleft {
       text-align:left;
       }
       </style>            
       <apex:form >
       <apex:image url="{!imageURL}" style="width:720px" ></apex:image>

       <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="720px" styleClass="alignfontleft" >
           <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="60%">
               <p style="font-size:18px;">FPIMS:</p> <apex:outputText value="{!Plan_Reviews__c.FPIMS__c}" style="font-size:18px;"/>
               <p style="font-size:18px;">Premise: <apex:outputText value="{!Plan_Reviews__c.Establishment_Address__c}" style="font-size:18px;"/></p>

           </apex:panelGrid>
           <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="40%">         
               <p style="font-size:18px;">Date:<apex:outputText value="{!currentdate}" style="font-size:18px;"/></p>
           </apex:panelGrid>

           <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="60%">
               <p style="font-size:18px;">DOB Job Number:</p><apex:outputText value="{!Plan_Reviews__c.DOB_Job_Number__c}" style="font-size:18px;"/>     
               <span style="font-size:18px;">Name of Contractor: <apex:outputText value="{!Plan_Reviews__c.Contractor_Name__r.Name}" style="font-size:18px;"/></span>
           </apex:panelGrid>
       </apex:panelGrid>  
       <div id="container1" style="width:720px">
           <span style="font-size:18px;">Rangehood plans submitted to NYC Business Accelearation have been examined and found to be unacceptable for an inspection and test at this time. This plan will be re-examined after the following defects are corrected:</span>
       </div>
       </apex:form>
   </apex:page>
   ```